# Irreducible components of $x_1x_4 -x_2x_3 = x_1x_3 - x_2^2=0$

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

I am going through introductory course on commutative algebra.
Let us have an algebraic set $X$ in $\mathbb{C}^4$ that is described as 
$x_1x_4 -x_2x_3 (f) = x_1x_3 - x_2^2 (g) =0$.

I am asked to find irreducible subsets of X, and to compare $I = (f,g)$, the ideal $I(X)$ which is all the polys that $h|_X$=0 and the intersection of ideals of the irreducible components.

So far
$f$ is a cone with the origin at $(0,0,0,0)$. 
One of the components seem to be $x_1=x_2=0$

---

[Here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/791789/477927) is a similar task that gives a way to make a problem easier in case there are elements that are reducible.

The task is taken from [here](https://ium.mccme.ru/postscript/f13/f13-elagin-ag1_04.pdf) and I have solved the same question for 
 $(x_1x_2-x_3^2=x_3-\lambda(x_1+x_2)=0)$ for $\lambda \in \mathbb{C}$ which is an intersection of a plane and a cone. But I can't imagine 4-dimensional space. I used the fact that homogeneous polynomial of second power is always reducible. May be that could help here.

**Update.** I have found three related questions:
[Checking one of prime ideals of X](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/95217/477927),
[Krull dimension of I(X)](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/167321/477927),
[Groebner base for the system](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/590804/477927).

thanks in advance

Comment: Since the polynomials are homogeneous, you can get away with three dimensional intuition viewing the zero-set as living in ${\Bbb P}({\Bbb C}^4)$. Then this is the [twisted cubic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Twisted_cubic) with a bisecant line.

In [M2](http://habanero.math.cornell.edu:3690/)
`R=QQ[x_1..x_4]`
`I=ideal(x_1*x_4-x_2*x_3,x_1*x_3-x_2^2)`
`primaryDecomposition I`
`toString oo`

`-- {ideal(x_3^2-x_2*x_4,x_2*x_3-x_1*x_4,x_2^2-x_1*x_3), ideal(x_2,x_1)}`

Comment: @Jan-MagnusØkland, are primary ideals of the ring the prime ideals here?

Comment: @Jan-MagnusØkland Do you mean that $x_1=0, x_2=0$ touches the twisted cubic at two different points?

Comment: It could be tangent, but generally, yes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assume $P=(a_1,a_2,a_3,a_4)\in X$ satisfies $a_1=0$. Then $a_2=0$ and $a_3,a_4\in\mathbb{C}$ can be arbitrary. This shows that $X_1=V(x_1,x_2)\subseteq X$, where $X_1$ is irreducible: $(x_1,x_2)$ is a prime ideal of $\mathbb{C}[x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4]$, because the factor ring $\mathbb{C}[x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4]/(x_1,x_2)\cong\mathbb{C}[x_3,x_4]$ is a domain. Note that a priori this doesn't imply that $X_1$ is an irreducible component of $X$, because $X_1$ could be properly contained in an irreducible component.

There are points $P\in X\setminus X_1$, for example points $P$ with $a_2\neq 0$. Take such a point $P$ and let $X_2$ be the irreducible component of $X$ containing $P$. Let $I_2:=I(X_2)$, a prime ideal minimal among the prime ideals containing $(f,g)$.

Multipliying the first polynomial by $x_3$ and substituting one gets

$x_1x_3x_4-x_2x_3^2=x_2^2x_4-x_2x_3^2=x_2(x_2x_4-x_3^2)$.

One has $x_2(x_2x_4-x_3^2)\in (f)\subseteq I_2$. Since $I_2$ is prime and $x_2\not\in I_2$ one gets $x_2x_4-x_3^2\in I_2$, that is $(x_2x_4-x_3^2,f,g)\subseteq I_2$. According to the second of the posts you are citing the ideal $(x_2x_4-x_3^2,f,g)$ is prime, hence $I_2=(x_2x_4-x_3^2,f,g)$.

Note that $X_1\not\subseteq X_2$, since $I_2\not\subseteq (x_1,x_2)$. Hence one can hope that $X=X_1\cup X_2$ is the decomposition of $X$ into irreducible components: let $P\in X\setminus X_1$, then $a_1\neq 0$. One thus gets

$a_2a_4=\frac{a_2^2a_3}{a_1}=\frac{a_1a_3^2}{a_1}=a_3^2$,

so that $P\in X_2$.

Comment: Thank you for a thorough answer. Could you say why is primeness of $I(X_1)$ holds? Is it because of radicality of $(x_1,x_2)$?

Comment: Do you mean, that $X_1$ is an irreducible component, i.e one of the maximal irreducible algebraic varieties, but this check should be done, because prime ideal may coincide with some irreducible variety but not an irreducible component.

Comment: I made some editing of the original post to address your questions. As you see the answer to your 2nd question is "yes".